# Is there a way to play audio programatically in a web app?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, html5-audio, progressive-web-apps

I am building a web app which involves playing a sound when new orders have come into the app. On desktop this all works fine.

However, on iOS, the audio does not play at all. After some [investigation](http://debuggerdotbreak.judahgabriel.com/2016/12/13/its-almost-2017-and-html5-audio-is-still-broken-on-ios/) I have discovered that iOS has limitations on playing audio.

- Only after user interaction
- Only while the page is active and in the fore
- Only while the phone screen is on
- There’s no way to keep the screen from turning off, so your audio will stop after the first song.

Is there a way to ask user permission to allow audio to be played programmatically?

Comment: Probably no, on purpose. It's to keep annoyances from random websites to a minimum. You can look into the web notifications API, but even there audio notifications aren't possible IIRC.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, the notification api has a sound property but it isn't supported by any browsers yet...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true ! No audio buffer before user request.
Use some popup or any animation nice for eye **to attract user for tap** .
One's you init play and in same time next code line pause you will initial buffering after that you can play audio programmability.
(Just like with autoplay problem for oldies versions)

in my memory ... android and iOS don't have a same behavior , it is about max number of audios that we can start buffer with this trick (one click or touch). You will need to test it. My devices android 6 for iOS 3 video/audios.

If you want same audio to play more times in same moment :
it is better to create more audio html tags with the same source .

> I 'm a fan of javascript but this time it is better to have html audio
>   tags in html form (subjective feeling/ no proof).

```
    var EXE_JUST_ONE_TIME = false;

    document.addEventListener("touchstart" , function(e) {

    if (EXE_JUST_ONE_TIME == false){

     EXE_JUST_ONE_TIME = true;

     document.getElementById("LaserShot").play(); // need for play pause just for buffering start
     document.getElementById("LaserShot").pause();
     // now you can play programmability from js 
     document.getElementById("LaserShot_CLONE").play();
     document.getElementById("LaserShot_CLONE").pause();

    }
    else if(EXE_JUST_ONE_TIME = true){

     document.getElementById("MakeReadyotherAudio1").play();
     document.getElementById("MakeReadyotherAudio1").pause();

     document.getElementById("MakeReadyotherAudio2").play();
     document.getElementById("MakeReadyotherAudio2").pause();

     EXE_JUST_ONE_TIME = 'NOMORE'

   } 


    }
```