# Playing audio through a .submit() event using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm building a text game using JQuery where players move through various rooms in order to escape from a cave (yes this cave has rooms, don't ask). They type commands into a form to navigate through the rooms. The game logic is all there and working, I'd just like to have a song play when they reach a specific room. So far I can get the clip to play using an HTML audio tag, but that only happens when the page loads.

What would a function look like if I wanted audio to play during a .submit() event?

Here's what my HTML looks like:

```
<audio id="song" src="Photos/song.mp3">
</audio>
```

My JS is a little too long to post it all here without confusing all of you (it's repetitive because I suck at JS) but the basic gist is I have a function that changes the currentRoom variable and updates the text based on what the current room is. So I was thinking the function would look something like this:

```
const $song = $("#song");
function playSong() {
  if (currentRoom = $r16) {
    $song.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44650634)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a .keyup() function, wasn't able to get the .submit() function to work. Here's what my variables and function ended up looking like:

```
      // Grab the audio html tag
      const $song = $("#song");
      // Tie the function to a keyup event
      $(document).keyup(playSong);
      // Function declaration
      function playSong() {
        // Keycode for the enter key
        const keyCode = 13;
        // If you hit enter and the current room changes to $r16
        if (event.which === keyCode && currentRoom === $r16) {
          // Hit the music
          $song[0].play();
        }
      }
```